# 15 Puzzle Shuffle Method Issues

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, winforms

I am making a 15 puzzle game in C# that allows the user to enter a custom row and column value up to a maximum of a 10 x 10 puzzle. Because of this I am having problems with the shuffle method. I want to make it so the puzzle is always solvable. By first creating a winning puzzle then shuffling the empty space. The problem is it is too inefficient to call every click event each time. I need a way to invoke the click event of a button adjacent to the empty space but not diagonal. I also use an invisible static button for the empty spot. The PuzzlePiece class inherits from Button. I am not too sure how to do this. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

here is what I have:

```
private void shuffleBoard()
    {
        //5 is just for test purposes
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            foreach (Control item in this.Controls)
            {
                if (item is PuzzlePiece)
                {
                    ((PuzzlePiece)item).PerformClick();
                }
            }
        }
    }

 void PuzzlePiece_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PuzzlePiece piece = (PuzzlePiece)sender;

        if (piece.Right == puzzleForm.emptyPiece.Left && piece.Top == puzzleForm.emptyPiece.Top)
        {
            movePiece(piece);
        }
        else if (piece.Left == puzzleForm.emptyPiece.Right && piece.Top == puzzleForm.emptyPiece.Top)
        {
            movePiece(piece);
        }
        else if (piece.Top == puzzleForm.emptyPiece.Bottom && piece.Left == puzzleForm.emptyPiece.Left)
        {
            movePiece(piece);
        }
        else if (piece.Bottom == puzzleForm.emptyPiece.Top && piece.Left == puzzleForm.emptyPiece.Left)
        {
            movePiece(piece);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey there.  Check out http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/, it's like the game development version of StackOverflow, perfect for questions like this.

Comment: So, `PuzzlePiece_Click` is too inefficient to be called every click? How many times are you clicking? 1000000 per second?

Comment: You really shouldn't derive your game objects from UI elements.  If you decouple the relationship, it ought to be much more straight-forward.  Make a board, shuffle it, and then create UI elements for each piece.

Comment: @justnS The OP is talking about rapidly calling the click event to shuffle the board instead of having designed the program to not rely on click events for its internal logic.

Comment: @paddy , thanks for the clearing that up!

Comment: FYI:  consider `this.Controls.OfType<PuzzlePiece>()` instead of checking types.

Comment: Thanks for rekindling a childhood memory of the 15-puzzle!  I think I'll grab some wood on the way home and make one for my kids tonight! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you I would separate out your model from your UI.

Create a class called `Puzzle`. This class will hold the state of puzzle and perform all operations on the state.

It's likely that you might implement `MoveLeft`, `MoveRight`, `MoveUp` & `MoveDown` methods. To shuffle your board you could just perform a (fairly long) series of moves by calling these four methods randomly.

Your `Puzzle` class would need to expose enough state for the UI to render itself.

Doing it this way you can simplify your code and make unit testing much simpler.

Comment: Listen to this guy, take all of your game's logic and implement it as a stand-a-lone class (or classes). The idea is that your interface to the game should not affect how the game's logic works. Although, I doubt he'll write unit tests.. but it COULD be a good exercise for learning!

Answer (score 11):

For 15-puzzles (and similar sliding-tile games), any arrangement of tiles is solvable If and only If it has an even parity.

Therefore, you should be able to just lay the tiles out randomly.  If the parity is even then its solvable as is.  If the parity is odd, then just swap two adjacent tiles to reverse the parity and then it's solvable.

See here for details on how to measure the parity: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifteen_puzzle#Solvability

---

Since the Wikipedia article has been changed so that it is no longer clear how to calculate the parity of a Fifteen-puzzle arrangement, I will explian below:

For any arrangement of tiles, you calculate the inversion by:

1. Counting all of the "*Inversions*".  An inversion is anytime in the sequence from the upper right-hand corner, across each row, down to the lower left-hand corner that a numbered tile is *lower* than the tile that came before it.  The first tile never counts as inverted (because it has no tile before it, so it cannot be lower than that tile), and you do not count the empty space.
2. Add to that the Row Number of the blank space *minus* 1.

This total is the Count of an arrangement.  If the Count is *even* then the arrangement has even (or 0) *parity*.  If the Count is *odd* then it has odd (or 1) parity.

Compare the parity of the starting arrangement to the parity of the target arrangement. If they are the same, then the puzzle is solvable, otherwise it is not solvable.  Since the standard target arrangement (space, 1-15 in order) has 0 inversions and the row number of the space is 1, then we get a Count of `0 + (1 - 1)` or 0, which is *even* so the parity of the target is 0.  Thus any starting arrangement that is also 0 is solvable.

Comment: does the parity argument stay if the empty square in the lower left corner?

Comment: That’s parity 1, I beleive.